# Android jack internal unknown error 415

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-jack-and-jill

I'm building AOSP 8 in a Mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.6) and Jack is failing with an unknown internal error

```
Internal unknown error (415), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
```

jack-diagnose shows this:

```
ps: illegal argument: -o
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
Port 8073 is used by another process (pid=), please ensure to free the port or change port configuration in '/Users/user/.jack-settings' and '/Users/user/.jack-server/config.properties'
ps: illegal argument: -o
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
Port 8072 is used by another process (pid=), please ensure to free the port or change port configuration in '/Users/user/.jack-settings' and '/Users/user/.jack-server/config.properties'
```

I looked at the ports and nothing seems out of the ordinary

```
$ lsof -n -i:8073 | grep LISTEN
java    70963 user   13u  IPv6 0xd32bb4a6a5b6116b      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8073 (LISTEN)

$ lsof -n -i:8072 | grep LISTEN
java    70963 user   11u  IPv6 0xd32bb4a6a5b616ab      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8072 (LISTEN)
```

The Jack logs show this:

```
16:14:44.181: WARNING: com.android.jack.server.router.ErrorContainer: Unknown request: 'POST /jack HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8072
User-Agent: curl/7.56.0
Accept: application/vnd.jack.command-out;version=1;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 800
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------9507228002c18ced

'
```

I tried manually stopping and starting the jack server and even changing the ports, but nothing seems to fix the problem.
I though this could be related to my CURL version, but I believe I'm using the correct one

```
curl 7.56.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0) libcurl/7.56.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.11
Release-Date: 2017-10-04
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

I ran out of ideas and I really don't know who what's causing this problem. I believe Google is deprecating Jack (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html) but I wonder why Jack is still enabled in AOSP by default. Setting ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK to false allows me to continue building, but that is just hiding the problem by not using Jack. Does anyone knows what's wrong? Does this look like a set up problem or something is in fact broken with Jack? I posted this question in the android-build mailing list but haven't heard anything so I'm hoping someone in the SO community might have an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same problem in Arch Linux. 
Build completed by downgrading curl from 7.56 to 7.55.1.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer because it indicates what curl version actually works. This fixed my problem

Comment: BTW, if you're using macPorts (like myself), you might need to follow [these](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort) instructions to install an older version of a port. [This](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/commit/29b6bfbc3be137223af6177a9efc6ca2d203ba20#diff-a4212cc1076e04f2728e4e87db652d0a) is the commit I used to install 7.55.1

Answer (score 1):

I am on Arch Linux too, the problem is definitely with Curl after is has been upgraded to 7.56, the error in the jack log is .android.jack.server.router.ErrorContainer: Unknown request: 'POST /jack HTTP/1.1   and mentions Curl 7.56, after downgrading the package there is no error and the build successfully compiles.  Not sure what has changed in Curl to generate this error though.  Might open an issue on Curl's Github or email their mailing list to see what the actua problem is.